# How to refer to properties values as variables in LESS?

Tags: less

Is there a way to use property names as variables in LESS?

For example:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: font-size * 2;
 }
```

The above snippet doesn't work, and I wonder how to get this effect?

Comment: still not supported, the CSS3 [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.

A workaround is creating a variable and assign the font-size to it. Then you can use this to multiply the value:

```
@fontsize: 16px;

h1 {
    font-size: @fontsize;
    line-height: @fontsize * 2;
}
```

Comment: I guess it isn't possible. Thanks